# Emulating a list in Python

Tags: python, list, types

I'm working with a class that emulates a python list. I want to return it as a python list() when I access it without an index.

with a normal list():

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[1,2,3]
```

what I'm getting, essentially:

```
>>> a = MyList([1,2,3])
>>> a
<MyList object at 0xdeadbeef>
```

I can't figure out which dunder method (if any) would allow me to customize this behavior?

I'd think it would be __ get __ ? although list() doesn't implement get/set/delete - i guess because it's a built-in?

Comment: I posted an answer, but actually I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve? If you want to show your list when you type `a` in the console, then you're looking for the `__repr__` method

Comment: What you are seeing in the interactive shell when you enter only the name is the repr (REPResentational) string. Same with the first one, where a real list emits a string that looks like the source code. Ideally, `eval(repr(object))` should work for simple types. So you are no "accessing" it when you show it like that, but "stringifying" it.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was confused about what was really happening there.

Comment: @VincentSavard actually your posted answer was correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the `__repr__` method in you class (and optionally the `__str__` method too), see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for a discussion on the differences.

Something like this:

```
class MyList(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        # iterate over elements and add each one to resulting string
```

As pointed in the comments, `str()` calls `__repr__` if `__str__` isn't defined, but `repr()` doesn't call `__str__` if `__repr__` isn't defined.

Comment: If you're only going to implement one, implement `__repr__` rather than `__str__`. `str` calls `__repr__` if `__str__` isn't defined, but `repr` doesn't call `__str__` if `__repr__` isn't defined.

Answer (score 5):

The method you are looking for wolud be `__repr__`.
See also [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple example:

```
class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self,arg):
       self.mylist = arg
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyList(' + str(self.mylist) + ')'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mylist)
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.mylist[i]

a = MyList([1,2,3])
print a
print repr(a)
for x in a:
    print x
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
MyList([1, 2, 3])
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to answer my own question - I believe it's the __ repr __ method that I'm looking for. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Here's what I came up with:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str([i for i in iter(self)])
```

Comment: I guess just `return repr(self.lis)` is sufficient.